Blazor environment component in .NET 8 versus .NET 6
In .NET 6, there was the environment component to check for current environment. The following code sample is taken from a vanilla Blazor Server project using .NET 6
<environment include="Staging,Production">
    An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
</environment>
<environment include="Development">
    An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
</environment>

This native component would conditionally render the children based on if the current environment name matches whats given in the include parameter.
It does not seem like Blazor with .NET 8 has this component. Is there a new one or should I just go ahead and make my own? I can easily make my own, but if a new one exist that does this there is no reason for me to make another.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#read-the-environment-in-a-blazor-webassembly-app


It does not seem like Blazor with .NET 8 has this component. Is there
a new one or should I just go ahead and make my own? I can easily make
my own, but if a new one exist that does this there is no reason for
me to make another.

The shorten answer is you need custom your own component to achieve your requirement.
Explanation
You can see the files in Blazor with .NET 8,  they are all razor components. Then you can check that environment is a Tag Helper. Tag Helpers aren't supported in components. To provide Tag Helper-like functionality in Blazor, create a component with the same functionality as the Tag Helper and use the component instead.
Reference: Tag Helpers aren't supported in components
For your requirement, you could also simply inject the IWebHostEnvironment service into your Razor components where you need to conditionally render content based on the environment.
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment

<h1>Welcome to My Blazor App</h1>

@if (WebHostEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Staging") || WebHostEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Production"))
{
    <p>An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.</p>
}
else if (WebHostEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Development"))
{
    <p>An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.</p>
}
else
{
    <p>No environment-specific message.</p>
}


This is the way.
